# Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

After updating dependencies I got `app not responding`  after  running
and I got this error in logcat

> E/MPlugin: Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport  E/MediaPlayer:
>   Should have subtitle controller already set

My dependencies :

```
dependencies {


            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.17'

    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.6'
}
```

Comment: Please share codes or steps that can be used to reproduce the crash and also more details like device type that you use. Or, you may want to check [GsmCellLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html) and also this [GitHub post](https://github.com/CellularPrivacy/Android-IMSI-Catcher-Detector/issues/788).

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue, but it is disappeared after installing the google play service from the android tools.

So it seems you need to clean and rebuild your project again to install this service, or just download it from android studio using the Android SDK Manager under Tools tab.

Comment: i have same issue, but this does not work for me any other solution?

Comment: First be sure you installed all suitable dependencies, then do build clean. many times the mismatching of libraries causing issues.

Comment: Anyone really found the right solution to this issue?