# ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp

Tags: java, android

Using a simple `Webview` leads to this error:

```
05-19 18:47:30.288 14503-14503/? E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
05-19 18:47:30.311 14503-14503/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
05-19 18:47:30.312 14503-14503/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
05-19 18:47:30.362 14503-14503/? E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
05-19 18:47:30.399 14503-14503/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
```

The `Webview` looks like this:

```
<WebView  
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I am using SDK 16 and the `Webview` is not used in any Java class. Furthermore, the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736890/no-drp-key-due-to-exceptionjava-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-android-webvie) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944220/what-does-this-mean-no-drp-key-due-to-exceptionjava-lang-classnotfoundexceptio?rq=1) were not helpful in this case.

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

Comment: Did you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658167/unsupported-class-com-mediatek-common-telephony-ionlyownersimsupport

Comment: Yes, I tried this one, too. But it doesn't help.